# ValueEventListener conta como conexão simultanea no Firebase?

Tags: android, ios, google, app, firebase

Se a minha aplicação no Firebase tiver 5 utilizadores e todos eles tiverem um valueListenerEvent ligado, esperando por alguma mudança na base de dados, tenho 5 conexões em simultâneo? Por exemplo, num chat usando o firebase com 105 users ligados ao mesmo tempo, isso são 105 conexões ao mesmo tempo, ou seja 5 users são "deitados" fora e nao conseguem conectar? Ou não é assim que a firebase conta as conexoes em simultaneo?

Answer (score 0):

O seu pensamento está correto, para cada usuário ativo é uma conexão no banco. E caso suas conexões estiverem no limite os novos usuários ativos não iram conseguir conectar na base. Outro cuidado que você precisar ter é não deixar conexão com o banco aberta em background, para não estourar o seu limite.

Lembrando que você tem mil usuários que instalaram seu app, isso não que dizer que você está com mil usuários simultâneos acessando o banco, porque cada usuário tem seu comportamento diferente.

Recomenda você da uma lida nesse exemplo aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20663071/612354